# graphql, how to filter by the very first node name?

Tags: gatsby, graphql-js

If I have `graphQL` nodes such as

```
allFile {
  edges {
  ...
  }
}
name1 {...}
name2 {...}
```

how can I filter by `name1` and `name2`?

If I can pass `name1` as a variable, how can I do this since they are the very first nodes?

In other words, the usual way would be

```
allFile (filter: {extension: {eq: "jpg"} }){
 edges {
  nodes {
   name
  }
 }
}
```

but how to do this if I want something like

```
(filter: {eq: "name1"}){
 edges {
  nodes {
   name
  }
 }
}
```

or directly something like

```
query ($name: String) {
  $name {
    edges {
      node {
        name
        message
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but doesn't seem to be possible (?)

---

**EDIT**

I'll try to explain myself better. If I had this tree:

```
AllMyPluginNodes {
  edges {
    node {
     name
```

I could filter through all the nodes for that node with a specific extension (business as usual).

The problem is that the name of "AllMyPluginNodes" is changing, such as

```
MyName1Nodes {
 edges {
...
MyName2Nodes {
  edges {
...
MyName3Nodes {
  edges {
...
```

And I know all these names, so I want to query specifically for those names.

In the first case I would do something like `AllMyPluginNodes(filter: { extension: { eq: "yml" } })` to retrieve all `yml` files under the `AllMyPluginNodes` node, but now, how can I do this?

`MyName1Nodes (filter: { extension: { eq: "yml" } })`

This obviously works, but I want `MyName1Nodes` to be a variable, and that's not a problem since I can pass variables through `createPages` context. The problem is, once I have this variable, how can I use it to query for `MyName1Nodes` provided that this is a "root" or "primary" node? Is it possible?

I can do something like

```
query($ext: String) {
MyName1Nodes (filter: { extension: { eq: $ext } })`
```

But I cannot do something like this

```
query($ext: String, $name: String) {
$name (filter: { extension: { eq: $ext } })`
```

**can I?**

Comment: Closed, thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not a way of using the results of a page query inside another query. Gatsby extracts your GraphQL queries via static analysis prior to evaluation of the page, so variables are not available. This is important to allow your website to compile down to static, server-side rendered pages that don't rely on a GraphQL server running (it's only running during build).

You *can* do as @ksav has outlined above if you want to generate pages or other effects based on the results of a GraphQL query: run a query (or several) inside of `createPages` and then make a call to `createPage` for each of them, passing in the resulting `name` as context, allowing it to be used as a variable in the page query.

Comment: I get what he is saying, and indeed this is exactly what I'm doing, createPages is sending the variable through context to the template, which is then querying for the specific node. The problem is that the plugin I'm using is creating nodes in the root of the system, so the plugin is not grouping their nodes under some AllMyCreatedNodes, but creating them just as "primary" nodes (if that's the way to say it). So the question remains the same, is it possible to filter based on the very first node of the tree?

Comment: So you only have one root node (`Query`), but I assume you mean that they're directly under it and you want to fetch them dynamically (i.e. without naming them). In this case, you can use the `onCreateNode` API and filter by `internal.owner`, then add them to a list elsewhere for you to consume inside of `createPages`. Not very straightforward, but it's do-able.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was thinking about, to modify the nodes created by the plugin and group them under a known node, so that later I can use it to query these nodes.

Comment: But somehow it is surprising that graphQL doesn't allow to search for nodes that are (in your words) directly under the root node. Actually this was the question, so the answer is that it doesn't allow it ... maybe you want to add this as an answer and I'll close the question

Answer (score 0):

[You can pass variables that can be queried via context](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/creating-and-modifying-pages/#pass-context-to-pages).

> The automatically created pages can receive context and use that as variables in their GraphQL queries.

In `gatsby-node.js` when you create the page, try adding the `name` field to the page's context.

```
createPage({
  path: `/${ edge.node.uid }`,
  component: postTemplate,
  context: {
    uid: edge.node.uid,
    name: name
  }
})
```

Once it's in the context, you can query the `name` in your graphql queries.

```
query PostByName($name: String!) {
  allMyPosts(filter: { name: { eq: $name } }) {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        data
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Furthermore, you can then access `name` in your template via `pageContext` prop.

```
import React from "react"

const Page = ({ pageContext }) => {
  return <div>{pageContext.name}</div>
}

export default Page
```

Comment: yes, but I'm not asking this. I'm asking how can I search for "allMyPosts", if I want to define "allMyPosts" as the value that the variable has, how can I define the graphql query?

Comment: So you do not want source that data from anywhere, but instead create some arbitrary source nodes during bootstrap?

Comment: a plugin is creating these nodes, for which I know the name, but how can I query them if the nodes are "root" nodes?